# Last few tasks in spark job are running very slow

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I was running below scala spark code on databricks. I am facing an issue like last few task are running very slowly. where 1st few tasks are completing with in seconds. I was tried with repartation of dataframe. But didn't helped. I am also not understanding what basics the tasks are divided to drocket node.

//#reading files from DBFS. And creating temp view on top of that.

```
val cdf_hsc_interim_nobed_main=spark.read.format("delta").option("header","true").load(s"${Interimpath}/cdf_hsc_interim_nobed")
cdf_hsc_interim_nobed_main.createOrReplaceTempView("cdf_hsc_interim_nobed")
spark.sql(s"REFRESH TABLE cdf_hsc_interim_nobed")

val cdf_hsc_facl_decn_bed_interim_main=spark.read.format("delta").option("header","true").load(s"${Interimpath}/cdf_hsc_facl_decn_bed_interim")
cdf_hsc_facl_decn_bed_interim_main.createOrReplaceTempView("cdf_hsc_facl_decn_bed_interim")
spark.sql(s"REFRESH TABLE cdf_hsc_facl_decn_bed_interim")
```

```
spark.sql(
          s"""
select
nb.*,
facl.id as facl_decn_id,
facl.seq_nbr as facl_decn_seq_nbr,
case when facl.id is not null then concat(substr(nb.cse_dttm, 1, 10), ' 00:00:00.000') else cast(null as string) end as eng_dt
from interim_nobed nb
left outer join decn_bed_interim facl on
(nb.id=facl.hsc_id and nb.facl_decn_id=facl.hsc_id)
where nb.facl_id is not null
union all
select
nb.*,
cast(null as int) as facl_bed_id,
cast(null as int) as facl_bed_seq_nbr,
cast(null as string) as engg_dt
from interim_nobed nb
where nb.facl_id is null
""").write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").parquet(s"${Interimpath}/set1_interimdelete")
```

UPDATE:
My spark version : 3.1.2
I am having two tables below are the table information.

First table
[image]

Second Table

[image]

Also checked spark UI in total output more than 50% of output records are only for last task.

Comment: Do share the Spark version along with the size of the data and the number of files.

Also, check the spark UI for any skews.

What is the size of your file(s)? Do you have too many small files?

Size of your cluster? Did you try upgrading the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Query Execution (AQE) is the best practice for speeding up the query.

In Spark 3.0, the AQE framework is shipped with three features:

- coalescing shuffle partitions
- switching join strategies
- optimizing skew joins

All the above operations are dynamically implemented.

Check the below link for better implementation.

https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/29/adaptive-query-execution-speeding-up-spark-sql-at-runtime.html

Answer (score 0):

From the query side, try filtering before joining. Even though the spark is smart enough sometimes a nudge from an Engineer helps.

```
select
    nb.*
    ,facl.id as facl_decn_id
    ,facl.seq_nbr as facl_decn_seq_nbr
    ,case when facl.id is not null then concat(substr(nb.cse_dttm, 1, 10), ' 00:00:00.000') else cast(null as string) end as eng_dt
from
    (select 
        *    
    from 
        interim_nobed
    where 
        facl_id is not null
    ) nb
    
left outer join 
    decn_bed_interim facl
on 
    nb.id=facl.hsc_id and nb.facl_decn_id=facl.hsc_id

UNION ALL

select
    nb.*
    ,cast(null as int) as facl_bed_id
    ,cast(null as int) as facl_bed_seq_nbr
    ,cast(null as string) as engg_dt
from 
    interim_nobed nb
where 
    nb.facl_id is null
```